# Sound not working! How to fix?

Tags: drivers, sound

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 32bit version and sound is not working. How do I find the correct driver and install it?

Answer (score 0):

You can download all missing audio video codecs from restricted-extras package.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I get error message. E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extra

Comment: type sudo apt-get update & then follow above mentioned line.